# Cron job not executing

Tags: server, command-line, cron, minecraft

I was making a cron job to save my Minecraft world from my ram every 5 minutes.
I tested the script and it seems to be working.

This is what the script looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh


VOLATILE="/home/jonathan/Games/Minecraft/Server/world/"
PERMANENT="/home/jonathan/Games/Minecraft/Server/world_storage/"
rsync -r -t -v "$VOLATILE" "$PERMANENT"
```

So then I went to add a cron job to run the script every 5 minutes, and it doesn't seem to be running it.

This is the script I used:

```
*/5 * * * * bash /home/jonathan/Games/Minecraft/Server/Backup.sh
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: cronjobs are run by root, who may have no permission to write on that folders. Does the script work if you run it as root?

Comment: @jasmines I'm having trouble understanding your comment. Root has permissions to write everywhere, while your first sentence states otherwise.

Comment: You should remove the `-v` on that `rsync` command. You don't want verbose output in a cronjob; you want a cronjob to only output anything if something goes wrong.

Comment: @jasmines cronjobs are run by the user that owns the cronab (the user you do the `crontab -e` with) and have the same rights as this user. The environment (PATH and more) are different than the one you have at login.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not specify how you added your cronjob. This makes a big difference: if you've used `crontab -e` within your own account, scripts are run with your user (and thus the crontab entry has one field less -- the user to run it, as that is known). If you simply copied your above snippet to `/etc/cron.d`, it would fail as you didn't specify a user (or rather as it finds no user named "bash"). So you should take the following steps:

1. update your question with information concerning how you added the cron job
2. check the system logs (`/var/log/syslog`; they could point to possible errors)
3. add some debug output to your `Backup.sh` script to see whether it is started

The third point can be achieved in multiple ways:

- add a `>>/tmp/testlog.log` to the end of your crontab entry (to redirect output to a file you can investigate; additionally, a `2>&1` would include output from the error console)
- add some lines to your script itself, like e.g. `echo "Backup.sh started">/tmp/testlog.log`

Moreover: As you intend your script to be run using `bash`, you should not tell it to use `/bin/sh` (which would make it use `dash` on a default Ubuntu installation), but rather `/bin/bash`. Then make it executable, and you can even omit the "bash" from your crontab entry.

**Update:**

According to your comment on my answer, you used `crontab -e` to create the job, and according to your systems logs it is executed, but the definition is rather

```
*/5 * * * * bash /home/jonathan/Games/Minecraft/Server/Backup.sh &>/dev/null
```

This redirects all output to the biggest storage in your system, the "black hole": `/dev/null` eats everything (but never returns anything). Redirecting STDOUT as well as STDERR this way robs you of any error report -- so you never know that they happened at all, let alone the details. For testing, you should omit the `&>/dev/null` part completely. Even if it works, you should only suppress unnecessary output -- as otherwise you never know when something goes wrong. So better leave out the ampersand at least, so Cron can report any occurring errors.

Furthermore: Once the output is redirected (as in your case to `/dev/null`), appending another redirect to the end will yield no results, as everything is already gone. So I have to adjust the above advice from "add ... to the end of your crontab entry" to "replace that in your crontab entry" ;)

Comment: You're welcome. If this solved your problem, you may "accept" it (by clicking once on the checkmark on the left to it). This is a good custom on all StackExchange sites -- and helps others to go straight to the most helpful answer (well, in this case it's only one, I know). Otherwise, if you have further questions, feel free to ask them.

Comment: Sorry i'm new to this site >_>  and I kinda messed up my full comment.
 
My full comment is:
Thanks for the answer.
I used crontab -e to make the crontab.
I done what you said and I have no luck at the moment.
The Syslog gives me


" Jul 16 16:53:01 jonathan-GA-890GPA-UD3H CRON[4568]: (jonathan) CMD (sudo bash /home/jonathan/Games/Minecraft/Server/Backup.sh &>/dev/null >>/tmp/testlog.log)" every 5 minutes.


And the testlog gives me nothing.
Any ideas?

Comment: The testlog *cannot* give you anything this way, as everything is already been eaten up by `/dev/null`. Change the line in your crontab to `bash /home/jonathan/Games/Minecraft/Server/Backup.sh >>/tmp/testlog.log` (i.e. kick off the `&>/dev/null` part) and try again. -- But what that log entry clearly states is that your job is executed. Which already answers your question ;) Now we just need to figure out why it is not doing what you expect -- and this I hope to see in the testlog.

Comment: The testlog says 

"
Backup.sh finished
sending incremental file list
./
level.dat
level.dat_old
region/r.-1.0.mca
region/r.0.0.mca

sent 3749210 bytes  received 94 bytes  7498608.00 bytes/sec
total size is 3748911  speedup is 1.00"

Seems to say what it says when I run the script manually.

Comment: And this is my updated script ( if it helps ) 


"
#!/bin/sh

echo "Backup.sh started">/tmp/testlog.log

VOLATILE="/home/jonathan/Games/Minecraft/Server/world/"

PERMANENT="/home/jonathan/Games/Minecraft/Server/world_storage/"
echo "Backup.sh finished">/tmp/testlog.log
#TODO: Check if both directories actually exist, skipped here for clearness
rsync -r -t -v "$VOLATILE" "$PERMANENT"
"

Comment: @user77242 Glad to read it worked out! So now you can remove the debug code, and replace the redirect in your cron job by a simple `>/dev/null`. This way "normal output" (e.g. progress) is sent to the "black hole", but you get a note when errors occur. And as this answer solved your problem, you may "accept" it as described above -- so other users can see immediately this problem found a solution.